# Designing pipeline for processing objects

Tags: c++, pipeline

Recently I have been asked a simple design question in an interview:

Suppose there is some data that needs to be processed in a pipeline fashion for efficiency. Suppose there are five tasks to complete and each task's output acts as input to the next one, and once a task completes for an object, it can process next one.

How to design that system? How the next task will get triggered? How the data from one task can be given to the next task?

Any ideas? This was asked in a C++ interview. So, a C++ oriented design will be good.

Comment: *"lazy initialization is the tactic of delaying the creation of an object, the calculation of a value, or some other expensive process until the first time it is needed."* Is the first thing that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interview question, so they want you to think aloud and demonstrate the depth of your experience. There is no one "design" or even "answer", and as such you should give as much thought on different cases as you can.

You can spend an entire book on pipeline designs so I won't (and can't) list all aspects you want to watch out for, but here are a few common ones:

- Watch out for bottlenecks
- Having a common protocol between the pipeline tasks
- Can the pipeline reject inputs, or even pass them backwards, how do you handle this
- Does it require lots of type conversions
- Can you parallelise it, and feed more data into the pipeline even before the first items have made it out